# Нужна ли запятая

Tags: запятая

Даже ложась в полночь(,) я всё-равно сплю до обеда.

Answer (score 1):

Нужна, обычный деепричастный оборот, к сказуемому не примыкает так тесно,чтобы выполнял роль наречия(шёл прихрамывая),не фразеологизм,стоит впереди сказуемого.